# Cannot insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data to database.
There is no error, but the database is still not being updated.
In the database, the `product` table contains:
productid, categoryid, productname, productimage, stock, price
and the `detailsales` table contains:
transactionid, productid, and quantity

The update one is working, but the insert one is not working at all.

Here is my code:

```
            <form action="doShop.php" method="post">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Product ID</td>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td>Product Image</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Product Stock</td>
                    <td> Quantity</td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<?=$row['ProductID']?>" name="productid"></td>
                    <td><?=$row['ProductName']?></td>
                    <td><img src="image/<?=$row['ProductImage']?>"></td>
                    <td><?=$row['Price']?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<?=$row['Stock']?>" name="stock"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    }
                    print mysql_error();
                ?>
            </table>
            <table>
            <tr><input type="submit" value="Submit"></tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Here is the doShop code:

```
                <?php
            include("connect.php");

            $id=$_REQUEST['productid'];
            $quantity=$_REQUEST['quantity'];
            $stock = $_REQUEST['stock'];

            mysql_query("insert into DetailSales(ProductID, Quantity)values('".$id."','".$quantity."')");
            mysql_query("update product set stock = $stock - $quantity where detailsales.productid = product.productid");
            header("location:shopcart.php");
            ?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you know there is no error? You're not checking `mysql_error()`.

Comment: [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) has been deprecated.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: if you want to be sure a query is working go to your mysqld.log, fetch the exact query mysql is receiving and paste it on your phpmyadmin query console.

Comment: @naryl: uh, easier to just do `$sql = "SELECT ..."; echo $sql`...

Comment: yup if you don't have any encoding problem, or the PHP is executed via AJAX and you don't want to capture the response, or if you are using a header() function that will redirect you somewhere else or just crash if you echo anything before it...

Answer (score 3):

You were trying to carry out calculations inside your query, instead I created a separate variable called `$total` to handle that for, you.

Like this:

```
 $total = $stock - $quantity;
```

Instead of this:

```
SET stock = $stock - $quantity
```

So, change the doshop code to this:

```
  <?php
      include("connect.php");
      $id = $_REQUEST['productid'];
      $quantity = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
      $stock = $_REQUEST['stock'];
      $total = $stock - $quantity;

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO DetailSales(ProductID, Quantity)
                   VALUES ('".$id."','".$quantity."')") or die(mysql_error());

      mysql_query("UPDATE product SET stock = '$total'
                   WHERE detailsales.productid = product.productid") 
                   or die(mysql_error());

     header("Location: shopcart.php");
```

Comment: exactly what I was about to write

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysql_query("update product set stock = $stock - $quantity where detailsales.productid = product.productid");
```

I believe this line is wrong and should be

```
 mysql_query("update product set stock = ".($stock - $quantity)." where detailsales.productid = product.productid");
```

Comment: sql can do math. `update foo set field=10-4` will set `field` to `6`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way instead;

```
$sql = ("insert into DetailSales(ProductID, Quantity)values('".$id."','".$quantity."')");
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if($res) {
    mysql_insert_id();
} else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```